# C: platform independence through void pointer and then casting

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm trying to do something to obtain platform independence.
I have a file "class_loader.h" which has

```
extern void* res_ota_load_module;
```

For a sample specific platform, this would normally be defined as

```
extern resource_t res_ota_load_module
```

with resource_t defined as (in another file):

```
struct resource_s {
  struct resource_s *next;        /* for LIST, points to next resource defined */
  const char *url;                /*handled URL */
  rest_resource_flags_t flags;    /* handled RESTful methods */
  const char *attributes;         /* link-format attributes */
  restful_handler get_handler;    /* handler function */
  restful_handler post_handler;   /* handler function */
  restful_handler put_handler;    /* handler function */
  restful_handler delete_handler; /* handler function */
  union {
    struct periodic_resource_s *periodic; /* special data depending on flags */
    restful_trigger_handler trigger;
    restful_trigger_handler resume;
  };
};
typedef struct resource_s resource_t;
```

But I'd like to keep it platform independent.

What I want to do now is, in a new file, "main_upnp.c" do the following:

```
    rest_activate_resource(&((resource_t)res_ota_load_module), "OTA");
```

where rest_activate_resource expects "(resource_t *resource, char *path)" as arguments.
The above code though gives the following error:

```
../../uJ/main_upnp.c: In function ‘process_thread_uj_process’:
../../uJ/main_upnp.c:257:2: error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
  rest_activate_resource(&((resource_t)res_ota_load_module), "OTA");
```

Can anybody please help me achieve what I want? Unsure on how to do it.

Comment: Normally you can cast `void*` to and from any other *pointer* type. In your case - to and from `resource_t*` not just `resource_t`.

Comment: You've given two incompatible declarations of `res_ota_load_module` -- one as a struct, the other as a pointer to a struct.  These are not at all interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting to and from `void*` is generally done on *pointers*. This means you can cast `resource_t*` to/from `void*` but not `resource_t` (of cource you *can* do something weird like taking first `sizeof(void*)` bytes interpreted as a pointer but it is actually UB and do not do this in general).

So as for your case - this:

> `extern resource_t res_ota_load_module`

Should be a pointer:

```
extern resource_t* res_ota_load_module
```

And then if

> `rest_activate_resource` expects `(resource_t *resource, char *path)` as arguments

you can do:

```
rest_activate_resource((resource_t*)res_ota_load_module, "OTA");
```

Or as a second option: let `rest_activate_resource` take `void* resource` as a parameter and then cast inside that function.